# Area Of The Region Bounded By An Ellipse Without Integration

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm going through serge Lang's Basic Mathematics in order to prepare for university mathematics.
In section 7 on area and applications one must find the area of a region bounded by an ellipse.

$\frac{u^2}{6} + \frac{y^2}{3} = 1$

Most examples of how to solve this i've found require integration. but i know that the area of an ellipse is

$πab$

however the answer is

π$\sqrt{18}$

I'd like an example of the correct way to do so without using integration as the text is supposed to be a logically contained text on mathematics required for calculus, not calculus itself. Or in other words could someone explain the reasoning as to why it's

$π\sqrt{18}$

and not just

$π18$

I know it's due to the $1^2$ not being distributed to the 6 or 3, but without better algebraic understanding I dont think i can necessarily discern exactly why.

Comment: The linear map $T(x,y)=(ax,by)$, maps a rectangle of area $A$ to a rectangle of area $|ab|A$ (in case $a=0$ or $b=0$, this means a rectangle is mapped to a line or a point). Since areas of regions are defined by approximating from outside/inside by rectangles, it follows that a plane figure $S$ with area $\text{area}(S)$ will get mapped to a set $T[S]$ with area $|ab|\text{area}(S)$. You might not like this answer, and argue this is essentially the idea behind integration, and you’d be right, but there’s no escaping this. Here, the $a,b$ are $\sqrt{6},\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: wait i just got it, thank you.